# How is it possible that the $ in jQuery acts like both a function and a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

$ in jQuery can be used like a function:

```
$('#myElement')
```

or like a variable:

```
$.post('send.php')
```

How can I imitate such behavior with my own class/function?

Comment: By following the same solution as jQuery. Just take a look at it, it is OpenSource. This is not voodoo magic, but plain javascript. And the concepts of what you call "a function" and "a variable" do not really fit here...

Comment: Everything is an object.

Comment: @Sandy: Everything but primitive values are objects.

Comment: @arkascha I tried, but it's so damn huge and I don't really know what to look for.

Comment: `$` is a variable. The **value** of `$` is a function. Functions are objects and thus can have arbitrary properties.

Comment: @Felix right, what you said. :)

Comment: @FelixKling Ok, but how do I declare it to behave like both? I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/okd0b851/ but I got "$.test is not a function"

Comment: Look again at the example in the duplicate question (you have to attach `test` to the function, not sure what you are trying to do with `this` here).

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't see the duplicate question, it didn't refresh by itself. Thank you very much I got it to work!